# Url Rewrite not working in umbraco 7

Tags: url-rewriting

I added the below code to  redirect in  urlrewrite.config

```
 <add name="regx"   virtualUrl="~/about/(.*)/2016/(.*)/12/"
redirect="Application"  destinationUrl="~/about/$1"
redirectMode="Permanent" />
```

And i added the below code to rewrite in web.config

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="regx">
      <match url="^/about/news/2016/(.*)/12/" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="about/news/2016/{R:1}/12" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This above code change my url from "//192.168.18.159:8741/about/news/2016/feb/12" to "//192.168.18.159:8741/about/news/". It get redirect to news page i am not able to get redirect to exact url as "//192.168.18.159:8741/about/news/2016/feb/12"

i am not able to get rewrite and redirect  i added the UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter.dll and used correctly in web config.

i need to change my url from "//192.168.18.159:8741/about/news/2016/feb/12" to "//192.168.18.159:8741/about/news/feb/"

Please give some solution as soon as possible. Thanks in advance